# Javascript object definition

Tags: javascript

Out the following two ways, which format for defining object is good considering performance and usage:

```
//Object created with public members defined using this.
var object1 = function () {
  var private_i = null;
  this.public_j = null;

  //public function
  this.public_func = function () {
  }

}
```

OR

```
//Object created with public members defined using return patterns.
var object2 = function () {
  var private_i = null,
  public_j = null,

  //private function will be exposed from return statement.
  _public_func = function () {
  };

  return {
    public_func : _public_func 
  };

}
```

Comment: Crockford recommends abolishing `this`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0

Comment: The first 1 it's simpler and less processing. you may try to check the performance on jsperf. :)

Comment: These 2 snippets do not produce identical results, hence they are incomparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two relates to inheritance and usage. Your `object2` always creates objects directly backed by `Object.prototype` and doesn't require use of the `new` keyword; your `object1` creates object backed by `object1.prototype` (which is in turn backed by `Object.prototype`) and *does* require use of `new`.

Neither is really "better" in any objective way, they are just two different ways of using JavaScript, which will have fundamentally the same performance. The first one is *much* more common, the second one is advocated by a small but vocal minority within the JavaScript community.

The `object1` example is more typically written like this:

```
function Object1() {
  var private_i = null;
  this.public_j = null;

  //public function
  this.public_func = function () {
  };
}
```

Note that the first letter in such functions is capitalized (by overwhelming convention).

The prototype thing comes into it if you're going to have functions that don't need access to `private_i`: You could put those on the object that will be assigned to new objects created via `new Object1` like so:

```
function Object1() {
  var private_i = null;
  this.public_j = null;
  //public function
  this.public_func = function () {
  };
}
Object1.prototype.someOtherFunction = function() {
  // Doesn't use `private_i`
};
```

You can also use prototypes with your `object2`, like so:

```
//Object created with public members defined using return patterns.
var object2Prototype = {
    someOtherFunction: function() {
      // Doesn't need private_i
    };
};
var object2 = function () {
  var private_i = null,
      public_j = null,

      //private function will be exposed from return statement.
      _public_func = function () {
      };

  var obj = Object.create(object2Prototype);
  obj.public_func = _public_func;
  return obj;
};
```